# Reading from files to arrays in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, binary

I have a trie-based dictionary on my drive that is encoded as a contiguous array of bit-packed 4-byte trie nodes. In Python I would read it to an actual array of 4-byte integers the following way:

```
import array
trie = array.array('I')
try:
    trie.fromfile(open("trie.dat", "rb"), some_limit)
except EOFError:
    pass
```

How can I do the same in Haskell (reading from a file to an Array or Vector)? The best I could come up with is to read the file as usual and then take the bytes in chunks of four and massage them together arithmetically, but that's horribly ugly and also introduces a dependency on endianness.

Comment: How much haskell do you know?  What have you tried or considered?  Are you familiar with deserialization libraries such as binary or cereal?

Comment: I tried only cereal so far which didn't seem to work; decoding the input as Arrays failed. As to my Haskell experience, I have a decent grasp of the fundamentals but probably haven't written more than 5000 lines so far in it.

Comment: Binary's not good either. It seems that they both expect some metadata besides the raw C-style array.

Comment: No, they don't.  You can just get elements as raw bytes and pack them into any data structure you desire.

Comment: Then what does the following error signify, that Binary throws when I try to decode my raw array as a UArray Int Word32: "Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 454936: demandInput: not enough bytes"

Comment: Haskell can't magically guess the format of your file - if its in a custom format you need to write a binary parser...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> encoded as a contiguous array of bit-packed 4-byte trie nodes

I presume the 'encoding' here is some Python format? You say "raw C-style array"?

To load the data of this binary (or any other format) into Haskell you can use the [Data.Binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary) library, and provide [an instance of Binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/latest/doc/html/Data-Binary.html#g:2) for your custom format.

For many existing data interchange formats there are libraries on Hackage, however you would need to specify the format. For e.g. image data, there is [repa-devil](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-devil).

For truly raw data, you can [mmap it to a bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring-mmap/latest/doc/html/System-IO-Posix-MMap.html), then process it further into a data structure.